# DAX formula for Time

Tags: powerbi, dax

**Time formula in Power BI**

What I am trying to do:
If any train departed `>= 59 sec`, then `"1"`, or else `"0"`.

The formula I am using:

```
=if([Actual-Planned]>=time(00,00,59),"0","1")
```

This is partially working. It does give me `"0"` in the case where `actual-planned` time is `59` seconds, whereas per formula it should give me `"1"`.

It works when I put it as `(00,04,59)` but does not work for seconds.

Has anyone come across this issue before?

Comment: What units does `[Actual-Planned]` return? Is it in seconds or is it a datetime?

Comment: Actual-Planned returns to hh:mm:ss. Example if its 1 min 5 sec, it will be 00:01:05. In case of 59 seconds it will be 00:00:59..

Comment: Can you give a few examples of what it is currently returning and what you want it to return?

Comment: right so this is my formula:                                                        =if([Actual-Planned]<=time(00,00,59),"RTSF","RTSA")

Answer (score 1):

right so this is my formula:
 =if([Actual-Planned]<=time(00,00,59),"RTSF","RTSA"), which means if any time a train is less than or equal to 59 seconds it will achived Right  time start or else fail, i guess i am getting the output now, as i changed to smaller than or equal to instead of greater. Thanks for your help